# Prime Counting on Intervals - is this deduction valid?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If there are at least $k$ primes on the interval $[a_{0},b_{0}]$, and there are at least $m$ primes on the interval $[a_{1},b_{1}]$, where $a_{0}<a_{1}<b_{0}<b_{1}$ and $k<m$, is it valid to deduce that there are at least $m-k$ primes on the interval $[a_{0},a_{1}] \cup [b_{0},b_{1}]$?

The question is relatively simple and the context is unimportant but I can't figure out if this is a valid deduction. Part of me also thinks that it would only be valid if k is bounded above and m is bounded below, rather than both m and k being bounded below.

Thoughts, help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All $k$ primes of $[a_0,b_0]$ and all $m$ primes of $[a_1,b_1]$ may lie in $]a_1,b_0[$.

For instance, take $[a_0,b_0]=[0,8]$ and $[a_1,b_1]=[1,9]$. Further, choose $k=3, m=4$.

Comment: I'm still confused, what about the other $m-k$ primes?

Comment: There may not be any "other" primes.

Comment: Ah I see it now, thank you. So, yes, k must be bounded above and m below, rather than both below.